# node-soap how to response a mesage(from server) using soap version 1.2

Tags: soap, soapserver, node-soap

I'm using node-soap library.
my project working with soap version 1.2 from the server side.

The problem is when im response a message to the client.

I made a debugging in node-soap library and i saw that the namespace of soap was built hard coded.
this is the code from node-soap, server.js file.

```
Server.prototype._envelope = function (body, includeTimestamp) {
  var defs = this.wsdl.definitions,
    ns = defs.$targetNamespace,
    encoding = '',
    alias = findPrefix(defs.xmlns, ns);
  var xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
    "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" " +
    encoding +
    this.wsdl.xmlnsInEnvelope + '>';
  var headers = ''; inc...
```

you can see the declaration of soap namespace is **xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"**

Now, i'm changed this specific code to be:

```
xmlns:soap=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope/\"
```

and it works.

There is a best way to fix the problem in this library? (like options??)
(like `forcesoap12headers:true`in client [it works excellent])

thanks for the help,
ariel